# Prove value of $\sin(15°)$

Tags: trigonometry, nested-radicals

I'm doing the following exercise: prove that 
$$
\sin(15°)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}
$$

I'm using this formula: 
$$
\sin(a-b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)-\cos(a)\sin(b)
$$

to get: 
$$
\sin(45-30)=\sin(45)\cos(30)-\cos(45)\sin(30) \\
=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\frac{\sqrt3}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\frac{1}{2} \\
=\frac{\sqrt3-1}{2\sqrt2}
$$

However I'm stuck, can't seem to get to the desired result. I tried multiplying for $$\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{\sqrt{3}+1}$$ but didn't get anything out of it. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: For what it's worth, the two answers are equivalent per [Wolfram Alpha](https://goo.gl/gVprXn), so it's only a matter of some kind of algebraic manipulation. Not like one comes to mind though. >_>

Comment: Also FWIW, if you had to solve this in an exam without a calculator, it's good to think of the approximate value of what you're finding. You can do it in your head in a few seconds if you know your square roots: $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}\approx\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2+1.7}}\approx\frac{1}{2\sqrt{4}}\approx0.25$ vs. $\frac{\sqrt3-1}{2\sqrt2}\approx\frac{1.7-1}{2\times1.4}\approx\frac{7}{28}\approx0.25$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They are equivalent.  Since $$(1 + \sqrt{3})^2 = 1 + 2 \sqrt{3} + 3 = 2(2 + \sqrt{3}),$$ it follows that $$\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3}} = \frac{1 + \sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}.$$  Then $$\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3}}} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2 (1 + \sqrt{3})} = \frac{\sqrt{3} - 1}{2 \sqrt{2}}.$$

---

It is also worth noting that we can obtain the desired expression more directly via the half-angle identity for $0 \le \theta \le 90^\circ$:  $$\sin \frac{\theta}{2} = \sqrt{\frac{1 - \cos \theta}{2}} = \frac{\sqrt{1 - \cos^2 \theta}}{\sqrt{2 (1 + \cos \theta)}} = \frac{\sin \theta}{\sqrt{2 (1 + \cos \theta)}},$$ where upon selecting $\theta = 30^\circ$ immediately yields $$\sin 15^\circ = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3}}}$$

Comment: Ah, this one makes more sense. The other method requires to do some odd algebraic manipulation, using half angle formula seems cleaner. Thank you loads!

Comment: @FernandoGómez Your solution is, in my view, more elegant, because the nested square root can be simplified further; therefore, the approach using the half-angle identity may have been what the author of the exercise had in mind, but the expression you obtained through the addition identity is preferable.

Answer (score 4):

Since, ${\sqrt3 - 1} = \sqrt{(\sqrt3 - 1)^2}= \sqrt2 \sqrt{2-\sqrt3}$
$$\frac{\sqrt3 - 1}{2\sqrt2} = \frac{\sqrt{2 - \sqrt3}}{2}$$
*Rationalising the numerator*
$$\frac{\sqrt{2 - \sqrt3}}{2}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}}= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Because $$\frac{\sqrt3-1}{2\sqrt2}=\frac{\sqrt3-1}{\sqrt2(\sqrt3+1)(\sqrt3-1)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2(\sqrt3+1)}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt2\sqrt{(\sqrt3+1)^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2\cdot\sqrt{4+2\sqrt3}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}}.$$

Comment: Can the down-voter explain me why did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from where you stack; after rationalization of denominator by $\sqrt 3 +1$, you got:

$$sin (15)=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2(\sqrt 3 +1)}=\frac{1}{2\times \frac{\sqrt 3 +1}{\sqrt 2}}$$

$$\frac{\sqrt 3 +1}{\sqrt 2}=\sqrt \frac{(\sqrt 3 +1)^2}{2}=\sqrt \frac{(2\sqrt 3 +4)}{2}=\sqrt {2+\sqrt 3}$$